Unable to retrieve user email from clerk middleware
I have a table in supabase called Users which needs email and authId.I want to update these user data from the clerk. However, I am not able to retrieve the email address from the clerk's middleware. I need help on how to get the email address.
I have tried to retrieve the email from UserId using getAuth by importing it from "@clerk/nextjs/client". But not successful.
import { clerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { supabase } from "./utils/supabase/supabase";
import { getUser } from "@clerk/nextjs/client";

const isProtectedRoute = (req) => {
  const protectedPaths = ["/add-listing", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"];
  return protectedPaths.some((path) => req.url.includes(path));
};

export default clerkMiddleware(async (auth, req) => {
  console.log("Middleware is triggered");

  const { userId, sessionClaims } = auth() || {};

  console.log("userId:", userId);
  console.log("sessionClaims:", sessionClaims);

  if (userId) {
    console.log("User is authenticated:", userId);

    const user = await getAuth({ userId });
    const email = user.email;
    const authId = userId;

    console.log("Email:", email);
    console.log("authId:", authId);
    const { error } = await supabase.from("Users").upsert({ email, authId });

    if (error) {
      console.error("Error inserting user into Supabase:", error);
    } else {
      console.log("User inserted or updated in Supabase successfully");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("User is not authenticated");
  }

  if (isProtectedRoute(req) && !userId) {
    return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Match API routes or specific protected paths
    "/add-listing",
    "/(api|trpc)(.*)",

    "/((?!_next|.*\\.).*)",
  ]
};




We import getAuth from "@clerk/nextjs/server" instead of the client version.
We use await getAuth(req) to get the userId.
To get the user's email, we use req.auth.user which gives us access to the full user object.
The email is accessed via user.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress. This assumes the user has at least one email address associated with their account.



import { clerkMiddleware, getAuth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { supabase } from "./utils/supabase/supabase";

const isProtectedRoute = (req) => {
  const protectedPaths = ["/add-listing", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"];
  return protectedPaths.some((path) => req.url.includes(path));
};

export default clerkMiddleware(async (req, evt) => {
  console.log("Middleware is triggered");

  const { userId } = await getAuth(req);

  console.log("userId:", userId);

  if (userId) {
    console.log("User is authenticated:", userId);

    const user = await req.auth.user;
    const email = user.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress;
    const authId = userId;

    console.log("Email:", email);
    console.log("authId:", authId);

    const { error } = await supabase.from("Users").upsert({ email, authId });

    if (error) {
      console.error("Error inserting user into Supabase:", error);
    } else {
      console.log("User inserted or updated in Supabase successfully");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("User is not authenticated");
  }

  if (isProtectedRoute(req) && !userId) {
    return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/add-listing",
    "/(api|trpc)(.*)",
    "/((?!_next|.*\\.).*)",
  ],
};



